# How to generate .net modules using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am writing a c# class library, where each class need to be compiled into different .net modules instead of as a single assembly. Is there any settings to get this done from VS.NET enviornment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "Build events" in VS.NET project properties to generate .net assemblies.
Under "Post build" event specify a batch file containing the following code.

```
csc /target:module YourClassName1.cs
csc /target:module YourClassName2.cs
```